# readline reverse-search-history C-r repeatedly finds next cmd, how to go back to previous?

Tags: command-line, history, readline

This is probably a very simple question, but I would really
like to find out if this is possible.

If I start a reverse history search with C-r and then press C-r again
multiple times I can search for further cmds in the history.

When pressing C-r quickly, it often happens that I miss a cmd that I want to use,
so I would like to find a way to go back to the previous cmd.

Is it possible with the current version of readline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `forward-search-history` command would do what you want — it will perform incremental search in the forward direction, and if you are already in the incremental search mode, it will just switch the search direction while keeping the current search string.

The problem is reaching that command. The default Readline bindings contain:

```
"\C-r": reverse-search-history
"\C-s": forward-search-history
```

But `C-s` is the terminal flow control character, which does not reach `bash` (although it would work in programs like Emacs, which change terminal settings to disable flow control processing). Therefore the default binding is useless, and you need to bind some other key to the `forward-search-history` command.

Another problem is that [key bindings with the Meta modifier do not work for incremental search](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-readline/2010-08/msg00008.html) — the Meta modifier actualy adds the ESC prefix, and ESC terminates the incremental search even when it is removed from the `isearch-terminators` variable value. Combinations with the `C-x` prefix also do not work — pressing `C-x` immediately terminates the incremental search. Therefore you need to bind a plain `C-<key>` to the `forward-search-history` command; however, all such control characters are already taken by readline commands, so you will need to sacrifice another command to free a key for `forward-search-history`.

Example `~/.inputrc` to use `C-t` for the forward search (replacing the `transpose-chars` command):

```
"\C-t": forward-search-history
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable XON/XOFF flow control:

```
stty -ixon
```

in your *~/.profile* or similar, then Ctrl+S will be recognized.

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/bay/blob/7df1fd5/config/bash/.profile#L26)

Comment: @GabiDavar updated